# Send an email to a "google group" Adding an attachment & having a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, email-attachments

When I am referring to "google group"  I mean a distribution list.  I send an email from a ruby on rails application.  The email is VERY simple.

`<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       BLAH
     </td>
     <td>
       Ummm
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>`

The email also has an attachment (VERY IMPORTANT)

- Senario 1) If I send this email directly to my email address everything works.
- Senario 2) If I send this email to a "google group" with me on the distribution list the content is removed from gmail's view (only the attachments are shown).  Oddly enough if you "show original" you can see the table was sent but it is being removed from gmail's presentation.  Additionally if I forward the email all content & show original is removed.
- Senario 3) If I send this email to a "google group" with me on the distribution list BUT my email address is not a gmail address the content is there.
- Senario 4)  If I send this email to a "google group" with me on the distribution list the content is fine if I do NOT attach a file.

I don't know how to proceed.  Thanks in advance!

### ======================

Comment: I remember something relating to this in a problem I had a few months back with emails which are encoded with multi-part plain text and rich text sections. Could you try and send the email in a non-multipart format and see if it works?

Comment: what is the attachment?? as your emails are working fine without attchments

Comment: I can have any attachment.  txt file or image file is all I tried

Comment: Did you try to upload the pdf/html/attachment file to Google Docs/Google Drive or some similar service and share a link to your html code? Would you get the same results? Since you mentioned that sending the email with no attachment is fine.

Comment: Eki, The people I am sending the emails to are people with a 4th grade educations.  I can't train 50,000 4th graders to learn something other than email. (Trust me I wish I could)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue.

The email was trying to post-pend a small bit of html.  BUT the html was below the ending `</html>` tag.

`<html>
     ...
     ...
   </html>
   <div>
      Disclaimer
   </div>`

Thus when gmail parsed the content it got confused and removed all content.  Odd that it worked if it was sent directly to gmail (not through a forwarding group) It also worked if there was no attachment.  It also worked if there wasn't a `<table>` BTW:  I found this because the in some clients the attachment was present but I was un-able to open them.  Turns out some clients merged the "Disclaimer" and the attachment.  WEIRD

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the gmail client, there is a chance that google adds the email to a tagged group (beneath 'All Mail') in the Categories menu, however the email remains visible. I believe there may be a way to manage that in settings (or if you use google apps you may need to have company level policies changed for you).

Comment: I can not ask every user of my app to change their google settings.  These emails are sent to 10 of thousands of users.  Thanks though.

Comment: Misunderstood, I thought it only impacts you, will think about it.. there bay be a way with tagging, or through email options. Are you using google apps, or free gmail? if the former is it the free or paid version of gapps?

Comment: I'm using ruby on rails & sendgrid.  I am sending the emails to a google group.  If I send the mail via ruby on rails via gmail to the google group I have the same issue.